# What's the difference between Memgraph main and replica instances?

Tags: memgraphdb

What exactly is the difference between Memgraph `main` and Memgraph `replica` instances. If `replica` is used when the `main` fails, they should be identical, right? Is that really so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph main is storing all the data and all write queries should go to the `main` Memgraph instance, while `replica` is just copying (actively) all the data and can serve read-only queries.

Answer (score 0):

There some diff between MAIN Instance and REPLICA Instance

Main Instance:

- Central Authority: It's the master copy of your data and accepts both read and write queries.
- Single Point of Write: All modifications to the database must go through the main instance.
- Higher Performance: Since it handles all writes, the main instance typically has higher performance requirements and resource demands.
- Single Source of Truth: Queries on the main instance reflect the most up-to-date state of the data.

Replica Instance:

- Read-Only Copy: It's a passive copy of the main instance. It only accepts read queries.
- Scalability and Availability: Replicas improve read scalability by distributing query load and enhancing redundancy and availability.
- Disaster Recovery: If the main instance fails, a replica can be promoted to become the new main instance, minimizing downtime.
- Delayed Data: Writes performed on the main instance take some time to replicate to the replicas, so their data might be slightly behind.